# Add an attachment to mailto link in PDF

Tags: pdf, mailto

I'm trying to add a mailto link in a pdf document that opens a new email with the said document as an attachment. Is this possible?
I have already added the subject and body of the mail.

Answer (score 1):

The mailto: protocol does not support attachments at all, PDF or otherwise. However, in Acrobat JavaSCript which is supported by a few other viewers, you can use a JavaScript Action to create a new mail message with the document attached. You can set a bunch of parameters like in the second example or just call...

```
this.mailDoc(true)
```

... to create a new blank message with the document attached.

Example 2:

```
this.mailDoc({
  bUI: false,
  cTo: "addressee@example.com",
  cCC: "CC_addressee@example.com",
  cSubject: "Your Subject line",
  cMsg: "Email body message."
});
```

Note: This code will not work in all PDF viewers and it is unlikely to work in browsers or on mobile. You'll need to test it in your specific use cases.